# How to create cookie with value as array()

Tags: php, cookies, yii

i am trying to create cookie like this...

```
   Yii::app()->request->cookies['username']= new CHttpCookie('username',array());
```

but it's giving me error say `setcookie() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

and [CHttpCookie class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpCookie#__construct-detail) also it's taking only string value...

so my question is how can i define cookie value as an array()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) to convert array to string. Why not [serialize](http://php.net/serialize)? Because [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) cookie data is dangerous: [PHP Object Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection).

Comment: @tinyByte, why it's better?

Comment: it will deal with utf chars also

Comment: @tinyByte, it's depend on php version only, IMHO.

Comment: you said unserialize will be dangerous.. can you pls tell reason? so i can more clear which to use...

Comment: @404NotFound, link added.

Answer (score 2):

[Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

```
Yii::app()->request->cookies['username']= new CHttpCookie('username',serialize(array()));
```

You'll need a corrosponding call to [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when you want to read the value on a subsequent request.

Comment: thanks it's working... how can i update value in cookie "username"... i tried Yii::app()->request->cookies['username']=serialize($username); but its' not working